# How do I use the recommended code to properly check the user's login state?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

For my app's structure, I think it would be very clean if I had one Kotlin file, `DBQuery()`, for anything related to Firebase/Firestore and then initialize this object on every activity (if this is a horrible idea, let me know). So on each activity I need to make sure that the user is still logged in (and later make sure that the user isn't banned, etc). The docs recommend to use the code below to check the current login state.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

I can't figure out how to modify this code to fit in my `DBQuery` class.

```
class DBQuery {

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val collUsers: String = "users"
    private val collRelationships: String = "relationships"
    private val tag: String = "DBQuery"

    fun checkLoginState() {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    // User is signed in.
                } else {
                    // No user is signed in.
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: The sample code you're showing is JavaScript, but apparently you are writing Kotlin.  So obviously that will not even compile.  Instead of that, you should look into the Android equivalent: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)

Comment: here is the correct link to the documentation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start)

Comment: @DougStevenson is it normal to add auth state listeners at the top of every activity? I'd rather somehow define one auth state listener in my DBQuery class and then use that in every activity to keep it clean, but I don't have enough kotlin experience to know if this is a futile idea or not.